# HammerJs fake multitouch and showtouches not supported on IE?

Tags: javascript, multi-touch, hammer.js

I can't seem to find a way to make the fake multitouch work on IE, currently testing on 10 and 11. Ive created the following example, picked the code from hammerjs examples page and tweaked a bit.

http://jsbin.com/tikimume/3/

Is this supposed to work with IE ? Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, see the below code it should allow your picture to be dragged, transformed, tapped, etc. The multitouch and fake gesture should be visible as well.

I have tested the code below in IE 10 AND 11

Code:

```
<body id="bodyElement">
    <div id="container">
        <img id="small" src="http://1800recycling.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/mona-lisa-lego1.jpg" width="40px" height="40px"/>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <img id="large" src="http://1800recycling.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/mona-lisa-lego1.jpg" alt="Colefax Classics" /> 
                <p id="coordinates"></p>
            </div>
    </div>
    <script src="hammer.fakemultitouch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="hammer.showtouches.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(ev){

            var isOpen = false;
            var posX, posY,
                lastPosX, lastPosY,
                bufferX, bufferY,
                scale, last_scale, dragReady=0;

            var t;
            var lastX;
            var lastY;
            var elemRect = document.getElementById('large');

            window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame; 

            //displays touch events
            Hammer.plugins.showTouches();
            Hammer.plugins.fakeMultitouch();

            var hammer = Hammer(bodyElement, {
                transform_always_block: true,
                transform_min_scale: 1,
                drag_block_horizontal: true,
                drag_block_vertical: true,
                drag_min_distance: 0,
                preventDefault: true
            }); 

            function SetDefaultImagePosition() {
                posX=0, posY=0,
                lastPosX=0, lastPosY=0,
                bufferX=0, bufferY=0,
                scale=1, last_scale, dragReady=0;
            }                   

            hammer.on('tap touch drag transform transformend dragstart dragend', function(ev) {
                ev.gesture.preventDefault();
                manageMultitouch(ev);
            });     

            function manageMultitouch(ev) {
                switch(ev.type) {
                    case 'tap' :
                        if(isOpen === false) {
                            $('#large').show();
                            isOpen = true;
                        } else {
                            $('#large').hide();
                            isOpen = false;
                        }
                        SetDefaultImagePosition();
                        break;

                    case 'touch' :
                        last_scale = scale;

                        break;

                    case 'drag' :
                        if(t){
                            if (typeof lastX === 'undefined' && typeof lastY === 'undefined'){
                                lastX = 0;
                                lastY = 0;
                            }
                            if(scale > 1) {
                                posX = (ev.gesture.deltaX + lastX * scale)/scale;//This is another workaround for the multiple drag glicth
                                posY = (ev.gesture.deltaY + lastY * scale)/scale;
                            } else {
                                posX = (ev.gesture.deltaX + lastX)/scale;//This is another workaround for the multiple drag glicth
                                posY = (ev.gesture.deltaY + lastY)/scale;
                            }
                        }

                        break;

                    case 'transform' :
                        scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(last_scale * ev.gesture.scale, 3));
                        t=false;
                        break;

                    case 'dragend' :
                        if(t){
                            lastX = posX;
                            lastY = posY;
                        } else {
                            t = true;
                        }   
                        break;
                }

                transform = "scale3d("+scale+","+scale+", 1) " +
                    "translate3d("+posX+"px,"+posY+"px, 0) ";

                requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                    elemRect.style.transform = transform;
                    elemRect.style.oTransform = transform;
                    elemRect.style.msTransform = transform;
                    elemRect.style.mozTransform = transform;
                    elemRect.style.webkitTransform = transform;
                });     
            } 
        });

        </script>
</body>
```

in the head all you have to add is a reference to hammer.min.js.

Comment: Thanks! In the latest versions this was fixed, I did got a reply back from them at github some time ago if I'm not wrong. This feature wasn't available before.

Comment: they have been improving their API significantly, but this code also answers another issue regarding browser compatibility. An issue with transforms. If you do think that is the correct answer please mark as it the correct answer!